# Python for loop with if condition (Dictionary Update)

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I am new to Python and need some help with the a for loop and if condition. Basically, in the code below, I am trying to find out the combinations of kWh and days that will result in the output of the equation to be less than or equal to 40.

The code produces the output, but it is inaccurate. For example, in the output, I should see an entry for 24 days and 1  kWh  (24:1), but the output is limited.

Any help would be appreciated

```
slice = dict()
days = range(1, 110, 1)
kwh = range(1, 5001, 1)

for (d, k) in zip(days, kwh):
    if 24 <= d <= 40 and (0.3856 * (k) + 6) <= 40:
        slice.update({d: k})

print(slice)
```

Current Output:

```
{24: 24, 25: 25, 26: 26, 27: 27, 28: 28, 29: 29, 30: 30, 31: 31, 32: 32, 33: 33, 34: 34, 35: 35, 36: 36, 37: 37, 38: 38, 39: 39, 40: 40}
```

Comment: Looks like you want the second element of zip to be consumption not kwh? Not sure how kwh is defined

Comment: kwh = range(1,5001,1). I have fixed the code block

Comment: using `zip` will not provide you all possible combinations of kWh and days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incomplete result is due to 2 reasons:

1. As Konrads mentioned, `zip` takes each element from the two lists, rather than return the combination of them, i.e., `list(zip(days, kwh)=[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), ...]`. This can be solved by nested loop as Konrads showed.
2. As the key, `days` can only have 1 pair of `key: values` in the dictionary. Records will be updated with replacement. When you get `24: 24`, you can never get `24:1`.

For Problem 2, reformatting the dictionary's style as `days:[the list of satisfied kwh]` will help:

```
slice = dict()
days = range(1, 110, 1)
kwh = range(1, 5001, 1)

for d in days:
    if 24 <= d <= 40:
        records = []
        for k in kwh:
            if (0.3856 * (k) + 6) <= 40:
                records.append(k)
        slice.update({d: records})

print(slice)
```

PS. Since you are new to Python, I recommend you to try using Debugger in IDE like PyCharm. It will show what are stored in each variable after cetrain steps, so it would be easier for you to find the problems of `zip` and missing old records.

Comment: Thank you :) . This is perfect and works flawlessly. I'll give it a try to PyCharm as well. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

```
In [32]: import itertools
In [38]: from collections import defaultdict

In [35]: days = range(1, 110, 1)
    ...: kwh = range(1, 5001, 1)

In [36]: slice = defaultdict(list)

In [37]: for d,k in itertools.product(days,kwh):
    ...:     if 24 <= d <=40 and(0.3856*(k)+6) <= 40:
    ...:         slice[d].append(k)
```

Zip makes a mapping for each of list1 with list2. It won't give you the cross product of 2 lists and the condition can satisfy for more values

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am getting an error. NameError: name 'itertools' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

zip takes an element from each list and returns a tuple,
thus you get tuples (1,1) , (2,2) and so on. What you’re after is a nested for loop I think:

```
for d in range(1,110):
    for k in range(1,5001):
        ...
```

Comment: I tried this approach before and it was still not giving me the entire output